# Como filtrar series repetidas en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2008

estoy utilizando SQL 2008 para hacer una consulta mediante inner join:

```
SELECT t2.intencion_id,t2.numpago,t3.orden,t2.importe
  ,SUM([importeaplicado]) AS importeaplicado
  ,t3.intfinanciamiento_interes
  ,t1.[estatus] FROM [APLICACIONES] as t1
inner join movcargos as t2 on t1.idmovcargo=t2.idmovcargo 
inner join intenciones_financiamiento as t3 on (t2.intencion_id=t3.intencion_id and t2.numpago=t3.intFinanciamiento_pagoNumero) where t2.idtipomovimiento=1 and t1.estatus='A' GROUP BY t2.intencion_id,numpago,importe,t1.estatus,intfinanciamiento_interes,t3.orden order by intencion_id,numpago,orden desc
```

entre las columnas que devuelve esta consulta, hay 3 que son series repetitivas: intencion_id, numpago y orden [image: resultado de consulta]
pero quiero que muestrelos registros de todos los intencion_id, todos los numpago pero solo el de orden mayor

como puedo hacer este filtrado?

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. Puedes incluir una muestra de tus datos, y luego mostrarnos el resultado deseado? A veces con palabras solamante no se comunica bien todo el sentido de la pregunta, especialmente cuando es una pregunta de consulta SQL.

Comment: Concuerdo con sstan, creo que no queda muy claro lo que buscas, por favor agrega un ejemplo

Comment: Creo que lo que tu buscas son funciones de ranking. Con una función de ranking te sale solo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como comenté, la pregunta no es muy clara. Pero mi interpretación es que para cualquier serie de registros que compartan los mismos valores para la combinación `intencion_id, numpago`, solo deseas que te devuelva el registro que tenga el mayor valor para la columna `orden`.

De ser ese el caso, esto se puede lograr usando `row_number()` para filtrar esos registros:

```
;with cte as (
    SELECT row_number() over (
              partition by t2.intencion_id, t2.numpago
                  order by t3.orden desc) as rnk,
           t2.intencion_id,
           t2.numpago,
           t3.orden,
           t2.importe,
           SUM([importeaplicado]) AS importeaplicado,
           t3.intfinanciamiento_interes,
           t1.[estatus] 
      FROM [APLICACIONES] as t1
      join movcargos as t2
        on t1.idmovcargo = t2.idmovcargo 
      join intenciones_financiamiento as t3
        on t2.intencion_id = t3.intencion_id
       and t2.numpago = t3.intFinanciamiento_pagoNumero
     where t2.idtipomovimiento = 1
       and t1.estatus = 'A'
     GROUP BY t2.intencion_id,
              numpago,
              importe,
              t1.estatus,
              intfinanciamiento_interes,
              t3.orden
)
select intencion_id,
       numpago,
       orden,
       importe,
       importeaplicado,
       intfinanciamiento_interes,
       [estatus]
  from cte
 where rnk = 1
 order by intencion_id,
          numpago
```

Probablemente hay una mejor manera de lograr lo que pides, pero tendrías que describir mejor tus tablas.

Comment: tu solución funciona perfecto, si este filtrado es el que buscaba realizar. muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo del todo los datos pero voy a asumir lo siguiente:

- Todos los grupos de filas tienen los mismos campos `orden`, es decir, si el `orden` mayor es `5`, siempre vas a obtener resultados con orden `1, 2, 3, 4 y 5` de los cuáles siempre vas a querer el de `orden 5`.

De ser cierto lo anterior la solución sería esta:

```
SELECT t2.intencion_id,t2.numpago,t3.orden,t2.importe
  ,SUM([importeaplicado]) AS importeaplicado
  ,t3.intfinanciamiento_interes
  ,t1.[estatus] FROM [APLICACIONES] as t1
inner join movcargos as t2 on t1.idmovcargo=t2.idmovcargo 
inner join intenciones_financiamiento as t3 on (t2.intencion_id=t3.intencion_id and t2.numpago=t3.intFinanciamiento_pagoNumero) 
WHERE t2.idtipomovimiento=1 
and t1.estatus='A' 
and t3.orden = max(select orden from intenciones_financiamiento)
GROUP BY t2.intencion_id, numpago, importe, t1.estatus, intfinanciamiento_interes, t3.orden 
ORDER BY intencion_id, numpago, orden desc
```

Por supuesto yo recomiendo usar `having by` así que si confirmas que esta solución funciona podría ayudarte a escribirla de otras formas más óptimas.