# Contador de operaciones repetidas de forma consecutivas

Tags: sql-server

intento realizar de forma global que de cada pedido me vaya contando de forma consecutiva, los tipos de operaciones que se repiten, como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

realice el siguiente query como prueba.

```
--query de la tabla original, el resultado lo inserte en una tabla principal
    select FINOPEDIDO AS No_Pedido,  FINOTIENDA No_Tienda,  fdFecMovtoPed Fecha_Operacion, fiTipoOp AS Tipo_Operacion,
     1 as Num 
     into   #Secuencia 
     from MOVIMIENTO_PEDIDO 
     WHERE finotienda=314
     and finopedido=802458

 
-- acá comienza el código para obtener el resultado que espero.
    WITH CTE AS(
        SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY Fecha_Operacion) 
                - ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY num, Tipo_Operacion ORDER BY Fecha_Operacion) grupos
        FROM #Secuencia   
    )
    SELECT
    No_Pedido,No_Tienda,
    Fecha_Operacion,
            Tipo_Operacion,
            NUM,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY Grupos, Tipo_Operacion, num ORDER BY Fecha_Operacion) AS Consecutivo
    FROM CTE
    order BY Fecha_Operacion
```

Al ejecutar este query filtrando nada mas un pedido de una sucursal me da el resultado que espero, pero cuando le quito el filtro y intento obtener el resultado de forma global, me da otro tipo de resultado que no es el esperado, alguien me podría apoyar dándome una idea de como poder obtener este mismo resultado pero de forma global, se lo agradeceré mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Vuelvo a repetir prácticamente lo que ya te respondí en tu anterior pregunta. Es ideal para estos casos el uso del row_number() para enumerar, que permite configurar bajo que condiciones se reinicia (partition by) y el orden (order by)

```
select FINOPEDIDO, 
       FINOTIENDA, 
       fdFecMovtoPed, 
       fiTipoOp,
       row_number() over (partition by FINOPEDIDO, FINOTIENDA, fiTipoOp 
                          order by FINOPEDIDO, FINOTIENDA, fdFecMovtoPed, fiTipoOp) as Num
       from MOVIMIENTO_PEDIDO
```

Comment: Como menciona @Patricio Moracho, y relacionada a las anteriores preguntas hemos notado que has avanzado con la respuesta.  [ve las formas de trabajar el over](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/31162/273432)

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a todos.

```
 WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY No_Pedido) 
            - ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY num, Tipo_Operacion ORDER BY No_Pedido) grupos
    FROM #Secuencia   
)
SELECT
No_Pedido,No_Tienda,
Fecha_Operacion,
        Tipo_Operacion,
        NUM,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY Grupos, Tipo_Operacion, num ORDER BY No_Pedido) AS Consecutivo
into #Consecutivos
FROM CTE
order BY No_Pedido



select No_Pedido,
No_Tienda,
Tipo_Operacion,
max(Consecutivo) as Consecutivo 
from #Consecutivos
where tipo_Operacion=12 
group by 
No_Pedido,
No_Tienda,
Tipo_Operacion
having max(Consecutivo)>=4


 --Este Query me funciono.
```